# how should I use qsort for pointers to sort by first character of it in c

Tags: c

```
/* problem of qsorting
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define INPUT "doc.txt"
#define OUTPUT "output.txt"
#define MAX_SIZE 500
typedef struct student // here I declare stuctures
{
    char name[20]; 
    int index;
    int code;
    int grade;
    char surname[20];
} student;
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) // initial part of qsort
{
   return ( *(char*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main()
{
    int i=0, m=0;
    int number=0;
    FILE *fo; 
    FILE *fi;
    char file[]={INPUT};
    char file1[]={OUTPUT};
    fo = fopen(file, "r"); // open the file
    fi = fopen(file1, "w"); // open the file
    student *studentPtr;
    studentPtr = (student*) malloc(MAX_SIZE*sizeof(student)); 
// here I use mallocation
    if(fo == NULL || studentPtr == NULL || fi == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (!feof(fo)) // reading of file
    {
        fscanf(fo,"%d %s %s %d %d",
        &studentPtr[i].index,
        studentPtr[i].name,
        studentPtr[i].surname,
        &studentPtr[i].code,
        &studentPtr[i].grade);
        i++;
    }
    i=m;
    printf("please insert a number upto 7:\n"); 
// because there are only   7 raws in the file
    scanf("%d",&number);
    m=number;
    if (number > 7)
    {
        printf("try again");
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            qsort(studentPtr[i].surname, 1, sizeof(char), cmpfunc); // ?
            printf("%d %s %s %d %d\n", // printing out
            studentPtr[i].index,
            studentPtr[i].name,
            studentPtr[i].surname,
            studentPtr[i].code,
            studentPtr[i].grade);
            fprintf(fi,"%d %s %s %d %d\n", // writing in the file
            studentPtr[i].index,
            studentPtr[i].name,
            studentPtr[i].surname,
            studentPtr[i].code,
            studentPtr[i].grade);
        }
    }
    free(studentPtr);
    fclose(fo);
    fclose(fi);
    return 0;
}
```

I am just beginner and sorry for obvious mistakes.
I cannot do qsorting properly.
i will attach txt file as a comment of this post.
could you guys tell me how to change first part of qsort not to get silly things, after that i will try to do that by myself

Comment: txt file with the name of 'doc.txt' looks like that:                                         1 Nikoloz Kalandarishvili 165853 5
2 Vache Kakhoidze 165849 4
3 Ucha Vekua 165840 3
4 Roma Beria 3 1
5 Margit Aarna 161516 5
6 Valodia Egorov 154713 2
7 Giorgi Qutateladze 165811 4

Comment: Don't put more information in a comment, especially if it needs formatting to understand. Edit your question and include it there, properly formatted.

Comment: Do **NOT** fill your post with random nonsense to get past the minimum text content requirements. That will **not** get you very far here. Please respect the quality guidelines and behave properly, or feel free to go elsewhere to ask your questions.

Comment: You need to read the documentation for `qsort` a little more carefully. The size and count arguments are just that: they need to tell `qsort` the size of each element and how many elements there are. They are *not* for providing the size of the substring or part of the data you want to compare. That should all be handled in the comparator function. Your current call to `qsort` is indicating that your list to sort has one element and that element is of size `sizeof(char)`.

Comment: you mean comment in a code or comment beneath the code?

Comment: I mean comments beneath the question, created by clicking "add a comment". There's an "edit" link you can click to edit your question to add more information if you need to.

Comment: so Lurker, can you tell me how should I change it in comparative function to get proper initial code? after that i will try to do it by my self